# Localize Settings.bundle with Localizable.strings instead of Root.strings

Tags: ios, localization, settings.bundle, localizable.strings

Because of the automated download of localization files in my app I was wondering if it was possible to localize `Root.plist` in Settings.bundle using `Localizable.strings` instead of `Root.strings`

Answer (score 1):

To use `Localizable.strings`, we have to use `NSLocalizedString` for referencing. Both docs for **Localizing Your App** and **Implementing an iOS Settings Bundle** don't mention such a method.

From my understanding, the `Settings.bundle` will be copied to a system folder outside app folder at the time of installation. Your app cannot reach this folder.

Comment: After research I came to the same conclusion. I resolved the issue by downloading a second file with localisations to the Root.plist in the Settings.bundle.